# knockout does not capture droppable textbox value.

Tags: knockout.js, drag-and-drop

When I drag a div to droppable textbox, I am able to change the value of textbox but knockout does not capture the value. If I put space or start typing then works. Check http://jsfiddle.net/nakres/sbtz1bb1/

```
<div class="draggable">mehmet</div>
<input type="text" class="droppable clearable"  data-bind="value:someText, 
valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']"/>

<span data-bind="text:someText"></span>
```

Comment: You don't have anything that would tell it to capture the value. Add something like `ko.dataFor(event.target).someText($(ui.draggable).text());` to your drop function.

Comment: That works but I have dynamic textboxes in my original code.   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput:value, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input'] " class="form-control input-sm droppable clearable" >

Comment: it is working for my dynamic textboxes too ko.dataFor(event.target).value($(ui.draggable).text()); thank you  Jason Spake